# Query to get Latest Record

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table which has only two columns (Rate, Date). Now the rate changes frequently every day. I am not storing the time, only date is stored.
I am looking for a query which could display the latest entry of each day.

Suppose my table has following entry -

```
records

+-------------------+--------------+
| Rate              | Date         |
+-------------------+--------------+
| 1                 | 01/01/2015   |
| 4                 | 01/01/2015   |
| 3                 | 01/02/2015   |
| 2                 | 01/02/2015   |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

Out put should be -

```
+-------------------+--------------+
| Rate              | Date         |
+-------------------+--------------+
| 4                 | 01/01/2015   |
| 2                 | 01/02/2015   |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

If I use Group by date, I get the 1st record. I always want the last record of each day. Tried writing a sub query, but doesn't work.

EDIT - 
I understand its almost impossible to find without having a key. But is it even possible with storing the time as well.?

Comment: You mean the one with the highest id? And which RDBMS?

Comment: No. Last record of each day. (irrespective of the id)

Comment: So how do we know which one is last !?!?!

Comment: This is the task eventually. I too am getting confused, hence asked.

Comment: I think the comment is that without a time, there is no way of knowing which is the latest.

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS table represent unordered sets, so technically, you can't do this without some kind of key. That said, you may get lucky by simply adding a surrogate PK.

Comment: Eventually I was thinking the same. Even if I put the time, It will still be difficult...

Comment: No. If you put the time (or, rather, change date to datetime) then the problem becomes trivial

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
SELECT T.RATE,T.DATES
FROM
(
SELECT RATE,DATES,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY DATES ORDER BY DATES DESC) 'Rows'
FROM EXAMPLE
)T
Where T.Rows = 2
```

Comment: It is not always the case where I will have 2 rows. I want to display every days latest record.

Comment: I know, that number 2 means the values from your row_number function which take the last records of each date. You could run this query with k of rows in your table and the result will be the last records of each date, 2 rows, 4 rows 10 rows, depends of the last records from you  table.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

```
WITH data (rate, "date") AS (
    SELECT 1, DATE'2015-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, DATE'2015-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, DATE'2015-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, DATE'2015-02-01' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    MAX(rate) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ROWNUM) rate,
    "date"
FROM
    data
GROUP BY
    "date"
```